# Redirection to home after clicking on back button

Tags: android, android-intent

I am creating an app, which will ask for password before opening any other app.
To start my activity i have created an intent which is having flags as ,
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

The locking/unlocking function is working properly,
but when i press back button it is not redirecting to home screen.

Comment: There is nice article about activity starting flags http://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/understand-android-activity-launchmode/en

Comment: use like this: `in.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);`

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you have not finished your home screen activity.. or you can try the onBackPressed() method

```
 @Override
        public void onBackPressed() {
        // INTENT FOR YOUR HOME ACTIVITY
        }
```